# SQL column name ambiguous

Tags: mysql

I am having trouble with a new IMDB like system I'm building. My specific issue is that when I run:

```
CREATE VIEW `directors` AS 
SELECT 
`stars`.`id` AS `movie_id`, 
`stars`.`title`,`stars`.`rating`, 
`stars`.`storyline`, 
`stars`.`star`, 
`people_list`.`name` AS `director` 
FROM `stars` 
INNER JOIN `stars` 
ON `movie_directors`.`movie` = `stars`.`id` 
INNER JOIN `people_list` 
ON `movie_directors`.`director` = `people_list`.`id` 
WHERE `movie_directors`.`enabled` = 1;
```

I get the following error:

```
#1052 - Column 'stars.id' in field list is ambiguous
```

All of the questions I've found on here seem to relate to when you don't prefix the column name with a table name or, in this case, a view name since I'm writing a view to build off another view

Comment: Replace `FROM stars` with `FROM movie_directors`

Comment: "FROM stars  JOIN stars" what? Is that intentional?

Answer (score 2):

You are selecting from `stars` and then `INNER JOIN`ing on `stars`:

```
SELECT ... FROM stars INNER JOIN stars
```

I think that you probably want to join with `movie_directors` based on your query.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a self join (starts table is used  two time) in this case you need  an alias for refer the proper table instance

```
  CREATE VIEW `directors` AS 
  SELECT 
      `stars`.`id` AS `movie_id`
    , `stars`.`title`
    ,`stars`.`rating`
    , `stars`.`storyline`
    , `stars`.`star`
    , `people_list`.`name` AS `director` 
  FROM `stars` 
  INNER JOIN `stars` as s2 ON `movie_directors`.`movie` = s2.`id` 
  INNER JOIN `people_list` ON `movie_directors`.`director` = `people_list`.`id` 
  WHERE `movie_directors`.`enabled` = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you are not aliasing correctly.

It should be something like

select ... 
from stars
inner join stars as *anothername*

Answer (score 0):

It looks to be ambiguous because you have two references to the `stars` table. Your `FROM` clause and your first INNER JOIN.

It looks like you are intending to join on `movie_directors` instead of  `INNER JOIN stars` clause. E.g.

```
CREATE VIEW `directors` AS SELECT 
 `stars`.`id` AS `movie_id`, 
 `stars`.`title`,`stars`.`rating`, `stars`.`storyline`, `stars`.`star`, `people_list`.`name` AS `director`
FROM `stars` 
INNER JOIN `movie_directors` ON `movie_directors`.`movie` = `stars`.`id` 
INNER JOIN `people_list` ON `movie_directors`.`director` = `people_list`.`id` WHERE `movie_directors`.`enabled` = 1;
```

Hope this helps!